# API Architecture: Should the API update the database on it's own? Or should there be another service to tell it to update the database?

Tags: web-development, rest, api

I am working on a project which has a requirement to records in the database every day. I currently have a REST API which does the usual CRUD functions. Should I create a service within the architecture which interfaces with this API to update the database? Or should this functionality be hosted within the API itself?

I apologize if this question seems a bit trivial and far-fetched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a *data access layer.*

The answer to your question is "Will there ever be anything else besides your API that might want to interface with the database from an object-oriented perspective?"

**Further Reading**
[Presentation Domain Data Layering](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PresentationDomainDataLayering.html)